# Google Apps Script calendar events using the Busy modifier

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script that modifies only my events marked "Busy" but can't seem to figure out how my script can see that information. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see any way to do that in the scripting api.  If it helps in your search, in other google APIs, it's called "transparency".  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific "transparency" field is not accessible via Google Apps Script. You can log something in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) for that item.

However, this is possible by jumping through a few hoops.

1. Use the [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/external_apis) with oAuth to talk REST with [Google Apps Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)
2. Look through the events there with the right transparency and record those event Ids
3. Now loop through the events in [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp) in Apps Script.
4. When the IDs match for the opaque event (busy), then make necessary changes to those events in Apps Script. Note - the ID that Apps Script returns has @google.com appended to the ID returned by the Google Apps Calendar API. You'll need to do a quick concat there.

This is a bit painful to get the right events in first part, but the second part of updating those events should all work natively in Apps Script.

Comment: Hi Arun... can you point me to any examples of Google Script code that successfully calls the Calendar API like this?  I need to set transparency, but can't figure out how to authorize and do the fetch to set it!

Answer (score 5):

For this Google now recommends to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#reference), which uses the same objects, methods, and parameters as the [public Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/).

It also includes support for [transparency](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource).